# PHP & Curl : post variable in square brackets

Tags: php, curl

I have to post a request with variable names that contains brackets to a distant webpage through Curl.

The distant form contains variables in brackets, for instance :

```
<input name="test[firstname]">
<input name="test[lastname]">
```

So, I build my Curl request like this :

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
  $postData = '';
   foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if($output === false)
    {
        return 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        return $output;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}

$params = array(
  "test[firstname]" => "Frank",
  "test[lastname]" => "Tomaso"
);

var_dump($params);
// array(2) { ["test[firstname]"]=> string(5) "Frank" ["test[lastname]"]=> string(6) "Tomaso" }

echo httpPost("http://www.mywebsite.tld/search/",$params);
```

The script doesn't return any error, but nothing appears on screen ($output). If I remove the $params content, it outputs the page but without any results. So I think there is a problem with the variable names in brackets. What do you think ?

Comment: Can you add the output from `var_dump($params);` in your question?

Comment: I've done what you asked.

Comment: Try `$postdata=http_build_query($params);` (values should be urlencoded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($params as $k => $v) 
{ 
    $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
}
```

This piece of code is incorrect because it does not URL-encode `$k` and `$v` as it should.

But you don't need to iterate over `$params`, encode the keys and the values and manually construct the query string. The PHP function [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) does all the hard work for you:

```
$postData = http_build_query($params);
```

You can even have:

```
$params = array(
    'user' => array(
        'firstname' => 'Frank',
        'lastname'  => 'Tomaso',
    ),
);
```

and `http_build_query($params)` still generates the correct query string for you.

However, if it still doesn't work then you should read the remote form carefully and send values for all the fields present in the form, including the submit button.

Comment: Perfect ! And I had to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); to get it working also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try instead of your array by

```
$params = array(
   "test" => ["firstname=>"Frank", "lastname"=>"Tomaso"],
);
```

Then when you send to curl you can try

```
$data_param = array('data'=>json_encode($params))
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_param);
```

In your dist url, you can use json_decode to decode data.